# Android studio HorizontalPicker library not working with integers

Tags: java, android

i'm fairly new to android developping. Right now i'm working on a project using the Horizontalpicker library (https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker). I got it to work, it works well at the moment. But it uses strings as the items to display. I want to change it to just an array of numbers (0-100) and it's not working.

My picker in my XML file

```
<com.wefika.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:values="@array/values"
        app:dividerSize="5dp"
        app:sideItems="@integer/numSideItems"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

The way i'm putting the items in the picker right now is by using the app:values="@array/values"
and having that array in the String.xml file

```
<array name="values">
    <item>Item 0</item>
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
    <item>Item 4</item>
    <item>Item 5</item>
    <item>Item 6</item>
    <item>Item 7</item>
    <item>Item 8</item>
</array>
```

When i change the text to like let's say "0" like following code it crashes on startup.

```
<array name="values">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
</array>
```

Comment: Post some error messages.

Comment: Ok so logcat isn't really showing a specific error message. However it does give me this: I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.widget.HwCustTextViewImpl

Comment: Edit your question with that information please.

Comment: insert <item> 0</item> instead of <item>0</item>